# I am receiving an error using xlwings when creating a function in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook, xlwings

I am using jupyter notebook to write python code into excel. Xlwings integrates python code and excel. I have xlwings installed into my excel page; however, when I create a function in jupyter notebook and import the function into excel. I receive a runtime error stating that excel is unable to locate xlwings32 and xlwings64. Does anyone have suggestions on what do? I would love a walk through of how you set up the UDF Modules for excel.

Comment: Here is your walkthrough: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html -- you currently have to import the functions from a python module, not a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Hi Felix,
Thanks for reaching out! How do I create a UDF inside of a python module so that I can use it? Specifically, I am "grouping by then summarise" similar to R functions. I am automating an excel sheet for work.

Comment: So I downloaded a module called 'Delivery_Data.py' and placed it in my path: C:\Users\gcantrell\Anaconda3. When I go into excel and click "Import Function" in xlwings ribbon, it says "File not found: xlwings32-0-0.23.0.dll".  In that pathway, I see xlwings 32-0-0.23.0.dll